# What is meant by "compiler helps implement the C standard?"

Tags: c, linux

I am reading / studying the book: [Linux System Programming: Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449339530) and quoting from this book:

> The compiler used in a Unix system—Linux included—is highly relevant
>   to system programming, as the compiler helps implement the C standard
>   and the system ABI.

What is meant by **compiler helps implement the C standard** ?

Comment: Poor wording. The compiler hopefully implements the C standard, probably with some extensions. Technically the standard library is not a part of the compiler; perhaps the author wants to make the point that the compiler stack consists of more than just the programs.

Comment: @triplee By implements the C standard, you mean, it should be able to understand the C syntax and create the binary accordingly right? Just want to make sure, I am not trying to correct you or anything, just trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not read the relevant paragraph.

> *compiler helps implement the C standard*

In general sense, C standard are a set of rules and/or guidelines, how the language syntax and semantics are to be used. To create and run a binary (executable), or better to say, to have an *implementation* of the rules mentioned in the standard, we need to have a compiler.

If I may, we can also say, in other words, compiler uses the C standards to generate an exectable from a C source code, which is C standard compilant.